# Why doesn't my schemas update in my map?

Tags: biztalk

I have a map in Biztalk which has a source-schema and a target-schema and I right-click each one and point to the reference, but schemas does not update, even when I have added some fields for them and built them. Maybe I should place them in the GAC also or something?

Comment: If your schema is in a separate assembly AND your reference isn't a project reference, then make sure your re-build the schema assembly.

Comment: In Biztalk 2013, re-building the referenced assembly was enough to get a suggestion from the mapper to refresh the schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the reference and re-add it. Doesn't need to be GAC'd.